# GParted error mkntfs -Q -v -F -L "" /dev/sdb1

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ntfs, external-hdd

after formatting my old HDD (ext4) into NTFS, this error appeared

```
mkntfs -Q -v -F -L "" /dev/sdb1
```

and

```
Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
The device doesn't exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

What can I do to fix it?

**edit**

here s the full report, does that mean I didnt just delete one but both! partitions? I m in Ubuntu live booting from DVD right now

GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Delete Logical Partition (unknown, 7.88 GiB) from /dev/sdb  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/sdb5  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb5 (partition)
start: 1937002496
end: 1953523711
size: 16521216 (7.88 GiB)
delete partition  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

========================================
Delete /dev/sdb2 (extended, 7.88 GiB) from /dev/sdb  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/sdb2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb2 (partition)
start: 1937002494
end: 1953523711
size: 16521218 (7.88 GiB)
delete partition  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

========================================
Delete /dev/sdb1 (ntfs, 923.63 GiB) from /dev/sdb  00:00:02    ( SUCCESS )

calibrate /dev/sdb1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 1937000447
size: 1936998400 (923.63 GiB)
delete partition  00:00:02    ( SUCCESS )

========================================
Create Primary Partition #1 (ntfs, 931.51 GiB) on /dev/sdb  00:00:44    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:33    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdb1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 1953523711
size: 1953521664 (931.51 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdb1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 274877906944  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 1000202567680  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 1000203026432  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 1000203083776  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sdb  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sdb1  00:00:11    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: ntfs
create new ntfs file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

mkntfs -Q -v -F -L "" /dev/sdb1  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
The device doesn't exist; did you specify it correctly?

========================================

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself: Just do **one pending action** (status lower left side of GParted window) **at a time**, first delete all sections then create new partition.

The error is gone on two different hard drives, so I guess that was it.